# How to delete duplicates in streaming data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1  structured streaming with kafka ,java8. 
My dataset looks as below for example

[image]

I need to find out the duplicates based on ColA ColB ColC and take the latest one among it based on ColDate and delete the rest.

i.e. 
from the above data result should be

[image]

How can it be done using spark streaming ?
I.e I will be getting data in streams like ... not sure when the duplicate comes if duplicates as specified earlier logic I need to delete records.
how can it be done generally in streaming scenario?

Comment: _"take the latest one"_ means to take the youngest? Why don't you `groupBy` and `min` per `ColDate`? Have you tried it? You'd then have to join with itself to get the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

In general streaming scenario you could check for duplicates using a hash table, which you can empty every x-hours.

```
  hashed =table['ColA','ColB','ColC']
  hashed=hashed.withColumn("row_sha2", sha2(concat_ws("||", *hashed.columns), 256))
```

To remove duplicates in a later stage you can drop them with

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy("ColA","ColB","ColC").agg((f.count("*")>1).cast("int").alias("e")).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have used the exactly-once data delivery notion ([here](https://blog.griddynamics.com/in-stream-deduplication-with-spark-amazon-kinesis-and-s3/)), had your duplicates were actually duplicates (i.e. same records, no intervening).

Even if you cache the 'latest' record that would result in storing N records in memory (worst case scenario). In addition, there is no guarantee to the consumer as to when they can consume the "right" record.

I think you should consider a batch job.

Comment: I need to clean the data as above , once I read the data from Kafka topic

Comment: Do you at least have a max timeframe for the possibility of getting a duplicate event?

Comment: What is the timeframe?

Comment: @ Nir Hedvat , sorry are you talking about timestamp or timeframe ? if timeframe you mean watermark delay period ? Its 5 min batch

Comment: What is the maximum time between duplicated events (that you are aware of...)